# Nested .then in javascript for firebase operation

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 functions like this:

```
export function senderMessageInbox(senderUID, recieverUID, 
    recieverProfileURL, recieverUsername) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(
                firebase.firestore().collection('messages')
                    .doc(senderUID)
                    .collection("inboxMessages")
                    .doc(recieverUID)
                    .set({
                        date: new Date().getTime(),
                        avatarUrl: recieverProfileURL,
                        message: "",
                        userId: recieverUID,
                        username: recieverUsername 
                })
            )
        })
        
}

export function recieverMessageInbox(senderUID, recieverUID, 
    senderProfileURL, senderUsername) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(
                firebase.firestore().collection('messages')
                    Same logic as above, but passing diff variables
            )
        })
        
}
```

I trying to call these in order but need both to complete separately before navigating to another screen. I have something like this:

```
function startChat() {
        console.log("senderMessageInbox");
        senderMessageInbox(senderUID, user.uid, user.profileURL, user.username)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("recieverMessageInbox");
            recieverMessageInbox(user.uid, senderUID, currentUser.profileURL, currentUser.username)
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("navigation.navigate");
            navigation.navigate('Messages')
        })
    }
```

Im logging the steps but, it seems like these are overlapping each other and causing overlaps in the db. Is this the correct way? I need these to finish in that order and then navigate to the screen only once they have been completed.

Comment: What is actually in the spaces abbreviated as `firebase logic here`?

Comment: @m_callens - Updated with firebase logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have the navigation happening asynchronously *with* the call to `receiverMessageInbox`. If you need them to happen sequentially, then you must structure the Promise execution accordingly.

```
function startChat() {
  console.log('senderMessageInbox')
  senderMessageInbox(senderUID, user.uid, user.profileURL, user.username)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('receiverMessageInbox')
      receiverMessageInbox(user.uid, senderUID, currentUser.profileURL, currentUser.username)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('navigation.navigate')
          navigation.navigate('Message')
        })
    })
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `async/await` to make this less visually confusing:

```
async function startChat() {
  console.log('senderMessageInbox')
  await senderMessageInbox(senderUID, user.uid, user.profileURL, user.username)

  console.log('receiverMessageInbox')
  await receiverMessageInbox(user.uid, senderUID, currentUser.profileURL, currentUser.username)

  console.log('navigation.navigate')
  await navigation.navigate('Message')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're leaving out some important code where you say `firebase logic here`, but I'm going to assume you're doing an async call of some sort there.

In this case, you have your `resolve()` statements in the wrong place. Your `resolve` is just returning another `Promise`, which is what the Firebase call will return.

Instead, call `resolve()` *inside* the Firebase call once it has returned and you have your data/have completed your updates.

Secondly, in your `then` chain, you need to *return* `recieverMessageInbox` instead of just calling it. So:

```
return recieverMessageInbox(user.uid, senderUID, currentUser.profileURL, currentUser.username)
```

#### Update, based on your added code

There's really not anything the outer `Promise` is doing, so you could just write your functions like this:

```
export function senderMessageInbox(senderUID, recieverUID, 
    recieverProfileURL, recieverUsername) {
        return firebase.firestore().collection('messages')
                    .doc(senderUID)
                    .collection("inboxMessages")
                    .doc(recieverUID)
                    .set({
                        date: new Date().getTime(),
                        avatarUrl: recieverProfileURL,
                        message: "",
                        userId: recieverUID,
                        username: recieverUsername 
                })
}
```

And apply the same technique to your other function.

And then, like I said before, make sure that you're returning inside your chained `then` statements:

```
senderMessageInbox(senderUID, user.uid, user.profileURL, user.username)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("recieverMessageInbox");
            return recieverMessageInbox(user.uid, senderUID, currentUser.profileURL, currentUser.username)
        })
```